# Yarn Global error `Package "/usr" refers to a non-existing file ...`

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

Running numerous `yarn global` commands (e.g., `yarn global list`, `yarn global add <package-name>`) results in the following error:

```
$ yarn global list

error Package "/usr" refers to a non-existing file '"/usr@file:../../../../../usr@/usr/local"'.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

### Additional info that may or may not be helpful

- Yarn installed via homebrew
- Yarn version: 1.22.10
- Path:

```
/Users/adam.sisk/.asdf/shims
/usr/local/opt/asdf/bin
/Users/adam.sisk/.yarn/bin
/Users/adam.sisk/dev/repos/learn/flutter/bin
/Users/adam.sisk/Library/Python/3.7/bin
/usr/local/sbin
./node_modules/.bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

- macOS 11.2.3
- `which yarn` = `/usr/local/bin/yarn`

Comment: I'm curious why you tagged this with "fish" but not "macOS". Is there some reason to think your problem is due to using `fish` rather than `bash` that you didn't articulate in the original problem statement? What happens if you execute the same "yarn" commands from a shell started by "/bin/sh"?

Comment: @KurtisRader thanks for that call-out, updated to tag "macOS" and removed "fish". Verified the result is the same no matter which shell the `yarn global` commands are executed from.

Answer (score 0):

> `@file:../../../../../usr`

This isn't documented very well, but `yarn global` doesn't work with relative paths. For example, instead of `yarn global add package-name@file:../package-name`, you have to say `yarn global add package-name@file:/path/to/package-name`. See [this issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2291).

Comment: And what is the solution? For me the `yarn global list`command does not work at all. What path should I modify?